# How would you make it so a parent's values wouldn't for an inherited object

Tags: javascript

So I have this code which inherits :

```
enemy = new Object(hawk);
```

The parent is this:

```
function CreateEnemy(name, health, damage){
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.damage = damage;
}

var hawk = new CreateEnemy("Hawk", 200, 20);
```

Whenever I do

```
enemy.health -= 10;
```

It changes the value of hawk.health as well, and I don't want it to do that.

Comment: I do not see any inheritance or constructing a new object with `enemy = new Object(hawk);` - the outcome actually is `enemy === hawk`. What do you intend to do?

Comment: I think you're missing a word in the title, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: It seems that you wish to clone the object - passing an object to `new Object()` [will **not** clone it](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2).

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `var enemy = Object.create(hawk);` instead.

Comment: Btw, it's odd to let a constructor begin with `Create`. You'd either expect `new Enemy()` or `createEnemy()` (or maybe `Enemy.create()`)

Comment: If you ended up with this code because you've noticed that instance specific properties were shared for child instances when you use `Child.prototype=new Parent()` than you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 It'll cover basic inheritance with JavaScript constructor functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
CreateEnemy.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new CreateEnemy(this.name, this.health, this.damage);
};
```

then do

```
var enemy = hawk.clone();
```

Now changes on one object will not reflect upon the other, as they are distinct `CreateEnemy` instances.

---

If you are looking for prototypical inheritance, [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will do it. Changes on `hawk` will then be reflected on `enemy` as long as the properties are not overwritten there:

```
var enemy = Object.create(hawk);
enemy.name; // "Hawk" - inherited
enemy.damage = 25; // assignment creates an own property on enemy
enemy.damage; // 25
enemy.health -= 10; // as does when getting an inherited value before:
enemy.health; // 190
hawk.health; // 200
```

Comment: Could you explain how the clone works? Am I suppose to replace the function CreateEnemy() that I had originally with that?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, `CreateEnemy` is not a `parent` object, it is a function that is creating an object `hawk` which you have previously made equal to the object called `enemy`. Hence, their properties are equal.

Comment: Thank you! So if I do enemy = object.create(hawk) that will be inheritance?

Comment: Use the `clone` method that **Bergi** mentions above and you can create as many different predatory birds as you like without them sharing properties.